# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 Horribly Slow to debug Javascript with IE 11

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I have web essentials installed and no other plugins and it just hangs for a long time until it finally debugs. Driving me nuts.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any work arounds?

Anyone figured out how to get the old F12 tools back and prevent Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 from doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is happening for me on Update 3.  Were you able to ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, I haven't found a way around and it isn't fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.... I ended up disabling "web essentials"  I think the problem was with the bootstrap template I'm using and the fact that I couldn't figure out how to disable the warning from jshint.  Thousands of styling warnings in code i didn't write seems like it might be the root cause but not 100% sure.

Comment: I uninstalled Web Essentials and it still is hanging forever when using IE 11 and debugging into typescript. (3.5 minutes exactly every time!)